# How do I sort a div structure as a table using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, css-tables

I am new to JQuery and I am looking for a way to sort a table that I have that I created completely using divs and no table structure.  I have same ids for the rows because I thought I can find a way to do it.  Here's my code:

```
    <div class="column_title">Column 1</div>
        <div class="column1">
            <div class="each_column">
                <span class="column1_class" id="row1">Value 1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="each_column">
                <span class="column1_class" id="row2">Value 2</span>
        </div>
            <div class="each_column">
            <span class="column1_class" id="row3">Value 3</span>
        </div>
            <div class="each_column">
            <span class="column1_class" id="row4">Value 4</span>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column_title">Column 2</div>
    <div class="column2">
        <div class="each_column">
        <span class="column2_class" id="row1">Value A</span>
        </div>
    <div class="each_column">
        <span class="column2_class" id="row2">Value B</span>
    </div>
    <div class="each_column">
        <span class="column2_class" id="row3">Value C</span>
    </div>
    <div class="each_column">
        <span class="column2_class" id="row4">Value D</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column_title">Column 3</div>
    <div class="column1">
        <div class="each_column">
        <span class="column3_class" id="row1">Value AA</span>
    </div>
    <div class="each_column">
        <span class="column3_class" id="row2">Value AB</span>
    </div>
    <div class="each_column">
        <span class="column3_class" id="row3">Value AC</span>
    </div>
    <div class="each_column">
        <span class="column3_class" id="row4">Value AD</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Being new to this I am unsure how to tackle this.  I have to use div structure so any guidance on how to go about this?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Can you create demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: FYI - If you want to [organize reams of data](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML_tables) then you *should* be using tables

Comment: There is a problem with your HTML ... `div`s are not closed properly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `display : table` . see this link

http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout

I'm not a big fan of this, but in your case it might help.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I had a similar issue and ended up writing a custom function to sort table built out of `<div>`s using pure Javascript.

**JSFiddle example**: https://fiddle.jshell.net/L4s73n44/43/

[image: div table using javascript sorting]

Actually, it is quite simple to program if all your `<div>`s have IDs (in my case, I'm using a helper class to dynamically generate the tables). In order to use my simple function, you need to use the following syntax:

- `<th>`: [table_name]_HEADER_COL_[COLUMN_NUMBER] `<div class="VISIBLE_HEADER SIZE_LIMITER XS_AJUSTMENT " name="RESOURCE_TABLE_HEADER_COL_2" id="RESOURCE_TABLE_HEADER_COL_2">`
- `<tbody>`: [table_name]_TBODY `<div id="RESOURCE_TABLE_TBODY" class="tbody">`
- `<tr>`: [table_name]*TR*[ROW_NUMBER] `<form class="VISIBLE_TR_ODD" name="RESOURCE_TABLE_TR_1" id="RESOURCE_TABLE_TR_1">`
- `<span>` within the table cells: [table_name]*COL*[COLUMN_NUMBER]_SPAN `<span name="RESOURCE_TABLE_COL_2_ROW_1_SPAN" id="RESOURCE_TABLE_COL_2_ROW_1_SPAN">MAXIME</span>`

**Note**: Beware the naming convention, the Javascript `getElementById()` function is case sensitive.

In the header cell, you can use the sorting function within glyphicon (in this example font-awesome glyphicon) like this:

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sortDivTableColumn('RESOURCE_TABLE_HEADER_COL_2', true);"></i>&nbsp;
    <i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sortDivTableColumn('RESOURCE_TABLE_HEADER_COL_2', false);"></i>
</div>
```

**Complete function code**:

```
/**
* Sort a specified column in a table (or <div> table) by using the tag IDs.
*
* @param columnID String ID of the column that we want to sort.
*
* @param asc Bool 
*       False: Sort in descending order.
*       True: Sort in ascending order.
*/
function sortDivTableColumn(columnID, asc)
{
    var match;

    if (typeof columnID === "string" &&
        (match = columnID.match(/^(\w+)_HEADER_(COL_[\d]+)$/))
    ) {

        var body;
        var html = [];
        var index = 1;
        var row;
        var span;
        var total;

        while ((span = document.getElementById(
            match[1] + '_' + match[2] + '_ROW_' + index + '_SPAN')
        )) {

            if ((row = document.getElementById(match[1] + '_TR_' + index))) {

                html.push({
                "data" : span.innerHTML, 
                "row" : row.outerHTML
                });

                } else { //can't fetch the whole row

                html.length = 0;

                break;
            }

            index++;
        }

        row = null;
        span = null;

        if ((total = html.length) > 0) {

            if (Boolean(asc)) {

                html.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.data.localeCompare(b.data);
                });

            } else {

                html.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.data.localeCompare(b.data) * -1;
                });
            }

            var buffer = "";

            for (index = 0; index < total; index++) {

                buffer += html[index].row;
            }

            html.length = 0;

            document.getElementById(match[1] + '_TBODY').innerHTML = buffer;

            buffer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Final note**: If you're not using `<span>`s within your table cells, replace this line:

```
while ((span = document.getElementById(
    match[1] + '_' + match[2] + '_ROW_' + index + '_SPAN')
)) {
```

by :

```
while ((span = document.getElementById(
    match[1] + '_' + match[2] + '_ROW_' + index)
)) {
```

Good success internet